# Mongo readtimeout from Mongo client

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

we have below replica setup for Mongo in AWS Ec2 with io1(10000 iops) and r4.8xlarge

1 primary,1 secondary ,1 arbiter nodes

And we have 2 type of applications writing/reading into Mongo with almost data nearly 200 million

now we are getting readtimeout/sockettimeour from  Mongo when application1 is having few writes an reads on Mongo during the time when application2 is performing huge Mongo writes & reads.

Application1 Mongoclient options:

```
    mongo.db.connectionsPerHost=50
    mongo.db.connection.timeout=4000
    mongo.db.max.wait.time=4000
    mongo.db.socket.timeout=4000
mongo.db.readPreference=primaryPreferred
```

And we are using Java Mongo driver which has by default Max connection pool size as 100 i guess

Please suggest if we need to make any changes to Mongo client options to get rid of this error

And can i assume that as im not setting connectionpool explicitly from mongoclient default value 100 is used? or connectionsPerHost=50 is nothing but connectionpoolsize ?

Comment: I guess the data length has exceeded enough to be handled on a single server. try `sharding` `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/`

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `waitQueueTimeoutMS` value of connection pool options.

> waitQueueTimeoutMS:
>   The maximum time in milliseconds that a thread can wait for a connection to become  available.

Refer this link for more details on connection pool options https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.waitQueueTimeoutMS